# SQLite database not available in .apk file? It showing no match?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

I create a simple login application in Android.
I inserted username and password in a SQLite database, by creating a database named MyDB and a table named UserLogin. I put it into assets folder of  my project in eclipse.
On emulator I can login successfully, but when I make an .apk file and put it on a mobile testing device, the login is not successful, why?

Comment: Well what have you done till ? please post the code .